# What are Fake Weighted Projective Spaces?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

What is the origin of and motivation for the notion fake weighted projective spaces? Could you please compare this notion to that of genuine weighted projective spaces, giving significant examples? Is there any good reference on fake weighted projective spaces as the one on  fake lens spaces? (Thanks to the "user 15817").

Comment: Topologists and algebraic geometers have different notions of a "fake" space. For a topologist, a "fake $X$" means a space homotopy-equivalent to $X$ but not CAT-isomorphic to $X$, where CAT is the DIFF, PL, or TOP category, depending on the context. In algebraic geometry, one typically replaces homotopy-equivalence with equality of Betti numbers. Answer to your question would depend on which of these you are interested in. Lastly, your question about Miles Reid is completely meaningless without context.

Comment: You should support your allegations about Reid with direct sources (not "I read that"), and you should also not impute mental states to him (as in whether he does something voluntarily or involuntarily). Stick to facts that you can directly support.

Comment: In reply to an comment via a suggested edit: the reason there are now 'fake lens spaces' is that this is what http://mathoverflow.net/users/35678/al-amrani suggested as an edit, which while not OP-account seemed to be the same person so that I approved and improved (I think, language wise) the edit. In general, please register an account than you can edit you own things directly. Please check the edit history click the time in the middle for the details, to see that the lens spaces originate from somebody with the same display name.

Comment: Sorry I take the above back in part. I misunderstood the meaning of a phrase. I make the change which I hope is now the intended meaning. Sorry, for the oversight.

Comment: @quid: While the edit is a major improvement, it still does not address the key (at least in my mind) question about the question: Does the OP address topological or algebro-geometric notion of "fakeness". The tags used in OP do not help here at all. It is like somebody asking the question "What is $H^2$?"

Comment: @Misha: I have nothing much to say about the question, I merely approved a suggested edit. This edit came from OP but was not done directly since they have more than one account (likely due to not yet understanding fully how the site works), so I felt it should go through. As I was already at it I tried to improve the language a bit (unfortunately getting the meaning wrong at one point due to choosing the wrong meaning of an 'as for', meanwhile corrected).

Comment: @quid: I see. Thank you for editing anyway!

Comment: Pleas do not use edit to comment on the post! You should be able to comment if you use the account you used to ask the question. To reply to it: I cannot "close" the question, once it is "on hold" for some time it will become closed automatically. Also I did not down-vote the question. But I am glad you found the edit acceptable in the end. Sorry again for the initial mistake. @Misha: there are some comments to you in this suggested edit in case you are courios I assume you know you can find it in the suggested edits history.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you would like to know about Fake lens spaces is on http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Fake_lens_spaces by Tibor Macko.

A Fake lens space is the Quotient of a sphere by a cyclic group acting freely and properly discontinuously. (The latter condition equivalent to the group being finite.)